# Is there any way on Stripe to send money back to the customer after getting profit on money of the customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

First, we take money from customers and as soon as we get the profit on the customer investment we want to transfer it back to the customer, is there any way on Stripe. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are building an investment platform and Stripe isn't a good fit, since you can't transfer back money to your customer.

You can somehow simulate by using Stripe Connect with each customer as a Connected Account, but it comes with different limitation on funds flow and fee, so it's not recommended.

Comment: Kindly share an alternative of Stripe to do this task?